# Make a div take up the entire width of the page

Tags: html, css

I am working on a small site. To make it easier to read I pushed all the content of the site into the center with.

```
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

The problem is that the div follows this rule and is only in the very center.

[image]

In the footer class I tried resetting the margins  and width by setting them back to 100% but that didn't work.

```
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/q6/pen/qEPWQK?editors=110)**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the entire `body` to 500px width, create a `div` for your main content, and then place the footer underneath.

```css
#content {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- Main page content here -->
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <!-- Footer content here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Either place the `.footer` element *outside* of the wrapper element:

[**Example Here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgMKeb)

In this case, use an element other than the `body` to function as the wrapper/container. I used an element with class `.container`:

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

---

As an alternative, you could also absolutely position the `.footer` element and add `left: 0; right: 0;` in order for it take up the entire width of the page:

[**Example Here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEGNRM)

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the css from your body into a containing `<div>` and put all your content in that and have your footer below the containing `<div>` and if the element is unique use `id`s not `class`

e.g.

```
HTML:
<body>
<div id="mainContent">
 <!-- Main site stuff here -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <!-- footer info here-->
</div>

CSS:
body{
 /*No CSS*/
}
#mainContent{
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want `margin-right: 100%;` for the footer?